# syntax error on sqlite in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook to run my sqlite database. I am new to sqlite and want to do a test from school. But when I run the commands, it is giving me syntax error but I know I got the command right. Let me show the cells in the jupyter notebook.
The first cell.

```
%load_ext sql
# Load SQLite database
%sql sqlite:///movies.db
```

The second cell:

```
%%sql

SELECT *
FROM movies
LIMIT 2
```

Everything runs fine so far, but when I call the third cell, it gives syntax error:

```
# create new table, cast1NF
%%sql 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cast_1NF;
CREATE TABLE cast_1NF (
    id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, 
    imdb_id VARCHAR, 
    cast VARCHAR, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id, imdb_id)
);
```

Jupyter notebook says there is a syntax error on `DROP TABLE` and then when I remove that line, it says there is a syntax error on `id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT`. It's bothersome really. Need help.

Comment: why is there a comma after ```table```?

Comment: what you saw there is a comment and not the code.

Comment: I removed the comment and it worked. How do you comment SQLite in Jupyter notebook please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the keyword `AUTOINCREMENT` unless you define the column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` (which by it self only defines the colum to be auto-incemented).

So, either define the column `id` to be the primary key and also define `imdb_id` to be unique:

```
CREATE TABLE cast_1NF (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    imdb_id TEXT UNIQUE, 
    cast TEXT
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bJVvwwi6ZDBndKaUpb6UUd/0).

This way there is no need to define the combination of `id` and `imdb_id` to be unique.

Or, if you don't actually need the `id` you can define `imdb_id` to be the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE cast_1NF (
    imdb_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    cast TEXT
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bJVvwwi6ZDBndKaUpb6UUd/1).

There is no `VARCHAR` [data type in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so I changed to `TEXT`.

Comment: I used your suggestions and it is still giving invalid syntax

Comment: @emekadavid you can check the demo links in my answer that tmy code is correct, so you are not using it correctly.

Comment: your codes are correct. The problem with the syntax error is that I used a python comment in the cell. that is, #. someone made a comment on that line so I removed the '#' comment and your code worked. thanks